# Infinite (finally-periodic) HList in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type, hlist

let's say I have an infinite sequence of actions, each of which returns the result of a certain type. Something like:

```
newtype Stream a = Stream (IO (a, Stream a))
```

But with `a` varying over time. I want to strongly type this sequence. It's obviously does not make sence for arbitrary infinite type sequence and naive approach such that:

```
data HStream :: [u] -> * where Cons :: Proxy x -> HStream xs -> HStream (x ': xs)

infiniteInt = Cons (Proxy :: Proxy Int) infiniteInt
```

will lead to an infinite type, which is not supported by Haskell's type system. But I don't see nothing wrong with a finally-periodic HLists (i.e. such what type sequence will repeat itself from some point: `[Bool, Int, Int, Sting, Int, Sting, Int, Sting ... ]`). And I also think that if we have some strongly normalizing way to describe infinite type or some way to provide an evidence of infinite type equality which can be checked in finite number of steps, it should be possible to typecheck program with such infinite types.

Does anyone have any idea how such types can be represented and used in Haskell? Let's start from infinite finally-periodic hlist for now, but I will also appreciate if someone has an idea how it can be generalized for wider class of infinite tupes and where generalization limits lays.

Comment: `data Stream a = IO (a, Stream a)` is strange, since you're using `IO` as constructor. Is that intended, or did you mean `data Stream a = Stream (IO (a, Stream a))`?

Comment: Sorry `data Stream a = Stream (IO (a, Stream a))` of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `HList`s infinite and periodic with this One Cool Trick!

When you add an element to your periodic heterogeneous stream, don't extend the list of types by which it's indexed. Rotate it.

```
type family Append x xs where
    Append x '[] = '[x]
    Append x (y ': xs) = y ': Append x xs

infixr 5 :::
data HStream as where
    (:::) :: { headHS :: a, tailHS :: HStream (Append a as) } -> HStream (a ': as)

myHStream :: HStream '[Char, Bool, Int]
myHStream = 'c' ::: True ::: 3 ::: 'x' ::: False ::: -5 ::: myHStream
```

Comment: You can define `data PeriodicHStream as where (:::) :: a -> PeriodicHStream (Append a as) -> PeriodicHStream (a ': as)` to fix the issue with the reversed order of values. It also fixes the "green slime" problem: "[The presence of ‘green slime’ — defined functions in the return types of constructors — is a danger sign](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/Pivotal.pdf)".

Comment: @user3237465 Oh, of course! It was right under my nose. I think I'd convinced myself that I wouldn't be able to call the constructor because GHC wouldn't want to unify `Append a as` with an arbitrary list. (In practice it works because you already know what `as` is, so all the type checker has to do is compute.) I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One general option is to switch from an `HList`, which encodes the types of all the elements, to a type-aligned list (or, more generally, a type-aligned sequence), which only ensures transitions along valid paths.

```
data TAList c x z where
  Nil :: TAList c x x
  Cons :: c x y -> TAList c y z -> TAList c x z
```

So you could encode your transitions, with some care, using a possibility-large GADT for `c` and an appropriate kind of your choice for `x` and `z`. Infinite type-aligned lists are no problem, because they're polymorphic in their final type argument.

You could probably use a McBride-style indexing scheme instead of an Atkey one to get more flexibility, at the cost of more complexity.

Comment: Looks interesting, could you please provide more complete examples and references to indexing schemas you mentioned?